# Aligning the axis of included graphics with the text in the document

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, horizontal-alignment

I'm trying to align a pgfplot graph with the text area of the document. I create the graph as a standalone pdf with the `scale only axis` option and `width=\textwidth` and so far I only managed to manually align it using `\hspace*{-1.5cm}` before the `\includegraphics{figure.pdf}`. Not only this is a bit tedious (I have quite a lot of graphs!), but it's hardly ever precise. Below is what I can do so far:

[image: hspace-alignment]

Is it possible to make this more automatic or is there any other way to do it?

Here is the code I have so far:

```latex
% --- main.tex ---
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document} 

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam cursus pharetra tristique. Curabitur sagittis libero sit amet ante fringilla, nec luctus neque laoreet. Morbi imperdiet convallis velit et elementum. 

\begin{figure}[h!]
\hspace*{-1.5cm}\includegraphics{figure.pdf}
\caption{Pellentesque molestie fermentum tellus ut posuere. Vestibulum euismod lectus quis augue commodo, imperdiet tincidunt felis viverra. Nulla facilisi.}
\end{figure}

Suspendisse id facilisis massa. Phasellus leo sapien, porttitor ac urna non, imperdiet maximus orci. Phasellus vel neque dui. Phasellus iaculis dictum dolor id iaculis. 

\end{document}
```

```latex
% --- figure.tex ---
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel={$f(x)$},
    colorbar,
    width=\textwidth,
    height=2cm,
    scale only axis,
]
\addplot {x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! The problem is that the problem is that the figure is too wide. What kind of solution do you expect? If you really (really meaning really really) want to do this, you could replace `\hspace*{-1.5cm}\includegraphics{figure.pdf}` by `\centerline{\includegraphics{figure.pdf}}` and tune the figure(s) in such a way that the `y label` takes + tick labels take as much space as the colorbar. But sooner or later this practice will backfire.

Comment: All of your images have the same dimensions? You can use the `trim` option to cut it. If they have the same dimension and the left label and color bar have fixed size, the values for `trim` could be constant.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the welcome! I'm experimenting with some designs for the main document, the idea behind this is to keep the axis borders aligned with text and caption, and leave the labels ticks and colorbar in the documents extra white space. A bit like when you add a note and it goes to the margin of the document. Does it makes  sense or is that possible at all?

Comment: All the axis have the same dimensions `width=\textwidth`, some are simple axis, some others are groupplots. The extra sizes comes from the ticks vales and labels in the axis and colorbar.